# Does Firebase's lack of region support have a significant impact on app performance?

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform, regions

Firebase currently doesn't support regions. My understanding is that it is based in the US central Google Cloud region.

If I am serving an app in London, which in turn calls a google cloud function, which in turn calls Google App Engine, which in turn calls a database, then I'm under the impression that this would involve circuitous routing.

For example:
1) Web Application served in London (CDN) ->
2) Firebase database (US Central) ->
3) Google App Engine (US Central) ->
4) Database request (London, UK) ->
5) written back to Firebase database (US Central) ->
6) served back to Web Application (London, UK).

With ~30,000km of cabling to travel through, would the general impact on performance / lag be sufficient to significantly affect app performance?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's essentially a feature request for Firebase/Google.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the firebase performance monitoring to gain insights, as you run you run your load tests, or simulations to make a better call. https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/